# How to create keyboard shortcuts for sub menu items

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

i am working with wpf.i got a problem is in creating keyboard shortcuts for menu items.
how to call sub menu item by keyboard shortcuts.
can anyone have idea on this?plz help me..thanks in advance..
my .xaml file is

```
    <MenuItem Header="_Open file" Name="open" IsCheckable="True"  Click="file_click"  InputGestureText="ctrl+o">

 <MenuItem.InputBindings>
   <KeyBinding Key="O" Modifiers="control"/>
                </MenuItem.InputBindings>
            </MenuItem>
```

my clickevent in .cs file is

```
   private void file_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {



        OpenFileDialog ofd;
        ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.AddExtension = true;
        ofd.DefaultExt = "*.*";
        ofd.Filter = "media (*.*)|*.*";
        ofd.ShowDialog();
        mediaElement1.Source = new Uri(ofd.FileName);
        listBox1.Items.Add(ofd.SafeFileName);
        mediaElement1.Play();



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your XAML:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="Open" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="Open" Key="O" Modifiers="control" />
</Window.InputBindings>
<Grid>
    <MenuItem Header="_Open file" Name="open" IsCheckable="True" Command="Open"  InputGestureText="ctrl+o" DockPanel.Dock="Top">            
    </MenuItem>        
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
 private void CommandBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) {
        OpenFileDialog ofd;
        ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.AddExtension = true;
        ofd.DefaultExt = "*.*";
        ofd.Filter = "media (*.*)|*.*";
        ofd.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: it generating error at command="open".the error is "Cannot convert string 'open' in attribute 'Command' to object of type 'System.Windows.Input.ICommand'. CommandConverter cannot convert from System.String."